# Node Js and Moongoose: How to loop into array of objects and delete a particular object and then update the whole document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My document schema is as follows:

```
 const CollectionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   ImageCategory:{type:String,required:true},
   imgDetails: [
       {
           _id: false,
           imageUrl:{type:String},
           imageName:{type:String},
           imageMimeType:{type:String},
       }
   ],
   Date: {
      type: String,
      default: `${year}-${month}-${day}`,
   },
},{timestamps: true,})
```

So in the database for example one document has multiple images with a single image category. What I am trying to do is I want to delete an object from `imgDetails` array.

Let me explain my question more precisely: `imgDetails` is an array

Explanation: I want to loop in imgDetails and then find (where imgageUrl === req.body.imageUrl) if its match delete that whole object which have that req.body.imageUrl and then update the document.

Please guide me on how to write such a query. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/qpl7lXbKAZE

Use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

> The $pull operator removes from an existing array all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition.

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  { $pull: { "imgDetails": { imageUrl: "xyz" } } }
)
```

Comment: I am using this querry and its not working 
     MultipleImagesFromRecentWorkModel.updateOne({},{$pull:{imgDetails: 
    {imageUrl:_ImageUrl}}});

Comment: @AbdulRehman What error are you getting ??

Comment: bro no error it says api run successfully but the db collection remain the same

Comment: @AbdulRehman Try to run it directly on the mongo console and check does It match anything `db.collection.find({ "imgDetails.imageUrl": "xyz" })`

Comment: yes still not working. Please sir can you come on call so I can show you my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231239/discussion-between-tushar-gupta-curioustushar-and-abdul-rehman).